# Avoid unnecessary SQL select query when getting entity proxy using entityManager.getReference() with hibernate and spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I'm struggling with unnecessary SQL select query when trying to get entity reference with Spring data repository using Hibernate as persistence provider.
My case concerns many times discussed question about using `entityManager.getReference()` in order to get proxy object with just initialized `id` value [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference) and [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/).
But this doesn't work as described.

I have following environment and code

1. Spring Boot JPA project with Hibernate
2. One dead simple entity `Foo`

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "d20_foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In my service code i'm just invoking `getReference` just like this

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

...
public void getFooLink() {
...
    Foo foo = entityManager.getReference(Foo.class,1L);
...
}
...

}
```

and in hibernate logs in debug mode I see, that, once I hit `getReference`, following select query is performed

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        foo0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        foo0_.name as name2_0_0_ 
    from
        d20_foo foo0_ 
    where
        foo0_.id=?
```

**Why is that? Why query is performed instead of just returning proxy object?**

I didn't hit any additional fields (like invoking getName() on returned object) and did all as was described in reference implementations.

I don't need extra query - `Foo` entity is a read-only object and I need it just as a referenced object to another entity.

Answer (score 3):

At last I guess the answer was simple.

It was a **debug mode (maybe especially in IntelliJ IDEA)** that fooled me and showed these kind of logs.
When I retried to monitor this code without debugging (just writing logs to console) - everything is fine.
Maybe when I'm doing debug my IDE call some property accessors (maybe of a `name` field) that causes Hibernate to perform select queries to initialise proxy.

So at last everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare JPA annotation on getter methods instead?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "d20_foo")
public class Foo {

    
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```